# I am having issues using a call function

Tags: vba

I have watched many videos on calling another sub. But with my code every time it gets to the line where it should call the function. It just finished the IF statement without following this command. Please note that this code is from a commandbutton inside of a userforum

```
Sub Begin_Click()

Unload BeginTheCode

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strDataRange As Range
Dim keyRange As Range
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wbkName As String
Dim wsName As String
Dim mName As String
Dim yName As String
Dim cName As String

On Error GoTo Err

'This command puts the other code in this workbook on hold'
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'This provides shortcuts for future use in the code'
    Set wa = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RE-I-A Raw")
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("I-A Data Copy (1)")
    Set wc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Untied Raw")
    Set wd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blanks")

Dim IMRCCSpec() As String
Dim IMRSup() As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim i As Integer

If Comittee = "IMRCC" Then
    Call IM
    Else
    If Comittee = "COO" Then
        Call COO
        Else
        If Comittee = "CFO" Then
            Call CFO
            Else
            If Comittee = "AURA" Then
                Call AURA
                Else
                If Comittee = "Distribution" Then
                    Call Dist
                    Else
                    If Comittee = "Legal" Then
                        Call Legal
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

Exit Sub
Err:
MsgBox "Error on Line : Sub Begin_Click() " & Erl

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub IM()

   On Error GoTo Err
   Dim IMRCCSpec() As String
   Dim IMRSup() As String
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim y As Integer
   x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wt.Range("C:C")) - 2
   y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wt.Range("E:E")) - 2
   ReDim IMRCCSpec(x) As String
   ReDim IMRCCSup(y) As String
   Dim i As Integer

   For i = 0 To x
       IMRCCSpec(i) = wt.Range("A" & i + 2)
   Next i
   For i = 0 To y
       IMRCCSup(i) = wt.Range("B" & i + 2)
   Next i

   'Call Something

Exit Sub

Err:
MsgBox "Error on Line : Sub IM()" & Erl

End Sub
```

No error messages occur. when I use the F8 command it goes through this line without any error and does not do anything

Comment: You dont need to use the word `Call` to call a subroutine, so you can take those out. Also, what is the value of `Comittee` when you step through it? Also, you should add `Option Explicit` before any of the routines (at the top of the module) and make sure all of your variables are declared.

Comment: Also, look into using `Select Case` instead of your nested `If` statements. It will be much cleaner.

Comment: Where is the diff between the subs (IM, CDO, CFO, ...)?  Seems like you can create one sub and pass commitee as argument.

Comment: in addition to above comments, seems like `Begin_Click` contains a lot of declarations and variable setting that are never used in the module. get rid of that. it only serves to confuse. (if you removed some of the code in the module for posting purpose, than ignore this comment).